# Execute SP using Repository Pattern and MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I want to execute 'Stored Procedure' using MVC 5 and Repository Pattern. I write code for it but it give me error like

> "**Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery(System.String, System.Object[])**"

My Interface

```
public interface IMemberRepository
{
   IEnumerable<MemberDetails> GetAll(); 
 }
```

Repository

```
public class MemberRepository : IMemberRepository
{
    ChatDBEntities entities = new ChatDBEntities(); // DB Entity which is generate by DB First Approach (EDMX)

    public IEnumerable<MemberDetails> GetAll()
    {
        string SP_SQL = "[GetMemberDetails]";
        var list = entities.Database.SqlQuery<MemberDetails> 
              (SP_SQL).ToList<MemberDetails>();
        return list;
    }
}
```

API Call (**Error** given at the time of call repository from API)

```
public class MemberController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IMemberRepository repository = new MemberRepository();
    public IEnumerable GetAll()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Please someone help me to find out a way to solve this problem.

Comment: `give me error like` Is that the **exact** error?

Comment: looks something is wrong in the return type of the method hence the signature is not mathing

Comment: this is the exact error and I also understand there is something wrong with return type functions call but couldn't find it.

Comment: That error message looks like a `MissingMethodException`. This can happen if you have some stray DLLs lying around. Try cleaning the project and removing any DLLs that shouldn't be there. Then try building again.

Comment: @DavidG after your suggestion I install re-sharper and remove all unused and duplicate dll from project. But still it gives me same error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve this problem. Actually this is an **MissingMethodException**. This happened for overlapping .dll inside my project. 
However, Clean Used & Duplicate .dll using Re-sharper isn't work for me. So, I re-create the project and after then this problem is gone.